# Spring MVC AutoPopulatingList error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm creating a form with "add row" items and used AutoPopulatingList for spring.  I started with the basic with just one row.

I have model:

ContractEntitlement.java

```
public class ContractEntitlement {

    private String category;

    getter and setter ....
}
```

I created a form class for the AutoPopulatingList:

CreateForm.java

```
@Entity
public class CreateForm {

    private AutoPopulatingList contractEntitlements;

    public AutoPopulatingList getContractEntitlements() {
        return contractEntitlements;
    }
    public void setContractEntitlements(AutoPopulatingList contractEntitlements) {
        this.contractEntitlements = contractEntitlements;
    }
}
```

For my controller:

CreateController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(Model model) {

    CreateForm createForm = new CreateForm();

//      CreateForm sbf = new CreateForm(); 
//      //sbf.getContractEntitlements().add(new ContractEntitlement());
//      sbf.setContractEntitlements(new 
//        AutoPopulatingList(ContractEntitlement.class)); 
    return "create";
}
```

For my jsp

Create.jsp

```
    <spring:bind path="createForm.contractEntitlements[0].category">
                <form:input path="${status.expression}" size="40" />
    </spring:bind>
```

Notice in my controller I have commented out a few line of codes as I was testing to see which one works but all fails and I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'contractEntitlement' of bean class [com.at.ccts.model.CreateForm]: Bean property 'contractEntitlement' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

If I use this in my controller

```
CreateForm sbf = new CreateForm(); 
    sbf.setContractEntitlements(new 
AutoPopulatingList(ContractEntitlement.class));
```

Error:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag - Invalid property 'contractEntitlement' of bean class [com.at.ccts.model.CreateForm]: Bean property 'contractEntitlement' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Am I missing something? Any ideas what causes the error?

Comment: Do you have model.addAttribute("createForm", sbf); in controller?

Comment: Yes, model.addAttribute("createForm", sbf);